# Docker run is not working as cron command

Tags: linux, cron, docker

The command below works nicely and puts "Hello from Docker." to out.txt

```
docker run -it --rm ubuntu echo "Hello from Docker." >> /home/ubuntu/out.txt``
```

Then when I open "sudo crontab -e" and put their line below, I am getting empty out.txt

```
* * * * *  docker run -it --rm ubuntu echo "Hello from Docker." >> /home/ubuntu/out.txt
```

Command below works and puts docker version into out.txt

```
* * * * *  docker -v >> /home/ubuntu/out.txt
```

from what I see "docker run" does not work for me from cron, and gives me no error/output. Do you have a clue why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without options `-it` these are for interactive terminal. But you are using in a script with no terminal, no interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try with user `root` on crontab, the command will be:

`* * * * * root docker run ....`

Comment: thank you, i tried, no effect, i already was running that as root. because i am configuring cron with "sudo crontab -e", that runs it as root